# Hide rows in Datagrid based on column value

Tags: react-admin

I have a `Datagrid` and one of the columns is `inactive` which is either null or contains a string with the date the row was set to inactive. Most of the rows in the Datagrid are null, but a few of the rows have a date in the inactive column.  I'd like to hide the inactive records in the Datagrid, but not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it on `List`:
`... <List filter={{inactive:false}}> <Datagrid> ... </Datagrid> </List> ...`

Comment: Forgot to mention that my API is basic and does not have any filtering or sorting.